# How can I pass an empty variable to a bash function and have it actually count it as a parameter?

Tags: bash

How can I pass an empty variable to a bash function and have it actually count it as a parameter?

Here's an example:

```
#/bin/bash

foo(){
    echo "foo() called with $# arguments.";
}

BAR=""
foo $BAR
BAR="fubar"
foo $BAR
```

The output of this is:

```
foo() called with 0 arguments.
foo() called with 1 arguments.
```

I would like both cases to be `foo() called with 1 argument`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just double-quote the argument:

```
BAR=""
foo "$BAR"
BAR="fubar"
foo "$BAR"
```

Output:

```
foo() called with 1 arguments.
foo() called with 1 arguments.
```

Double-quoting variables is a best practice for shell programming because it prevents problems with whitespace and special (e.g. `*`) characters. The only case where you must not quote it is when you actually want Bash to word-split a variable's content or expand wildcard characters:

```
BAR="a b c"
foo "$BAR"
foo $BAR
BAR="*"
echo "$BAR"
echo $BAR
```

Output:

```
foo() called with 1 arguments.
foo() called with 3 arguments.
*
test.sh
```

Comment: I would phrase it stronger: *always* quote your variables unless you specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the value.

Answer (score 0):

Quote BAR:

```
foo "$BAR"
```

That will send empty string to foo.